# Add Text and Value in ComboBox VB6

Tags: combobox, vb6

I learn visual basic, but I am confused when add value and text in combo box.

This is my sample data:

```
Kode(value) | Name (Text)
DTR001 | Director
SVS005 | Supervisor
MKR001 | Marketing
```

In HTML code like this:

```html
<select name="mydata">
    <option value="DTR001">Director</option>
    <option value="SVS005">Supervisor</option>
    <option value="MKR001">Marketing </option>
</select>
```

How to save add value in combo box VB 6, this is my shortcode:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
     cmb1.AddItem "test1"
     cmb1.AddItem "test2"
     cmb1.AddItem "test3"
End Sub
    
Private Sub cmb_jabatan_Click()
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding both text and an ID value to a VB6 combobox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11745622/adding-both-text-and-an-id-value-to-a-vb6-combobox)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to maintain an array of the value strings, you can access the correct element by looking at the zero based list index of the combobox item.

```
Private mValues() As String

Private Sub Form_Load()
    ReDim mValues(2)
    mValues(0) = "DTR001"  '// ListIndex 0
    mValues(1) = "SVS005"
    mValues(2) = "MKR001"

    cmb1.AddItem "Director"
    cmb1.AddItem "Supervisor"
    cmb1.AddItem "Marketing"
End Sub

Private Sub cmb1_Click()
    MsgBox cmb1.List(cmb1.ListIndex) & "/" & mValues(cmb1.ListIndex)
End Sub
```

You can only directly associate an arbitrary integer with a combobox item using `ItemData`

```
.AddItem "Foo"
.ItemData(.NewIndex) = 42
```

And retrieve with

```
cmb1.ItemData(listIndex)
```

You could use this instead of `.ListIndex` to link to the array if needed.

Comment: if i conect database how to script, to dynamic value >>
ReDim mValues(2) mybe like this ReDim mValues(dynamic value)