# How do I populate a ComboBox in VB6 from a SQL recordset?

Tags: sql-server, combobox, vb6

I'm trying to populate a ComboBox in VB6 using a RecordSet I pulled from SQL.  I've written a stored procedure in SQL that returns a RecordSet that looks like this:

RecordSet:

[image]

I've written a function in VB6 that assigns that RecordSet to a variable: `rsRetData`.  On my user form I have a ComboBox called `cboxRejectReasons`.  I want to have all the `Descriptions` from the RecordSet listed in the dropdown AND have the associated `SelectCode` still attached to the `Description`.

Here is the stored procedure code (sorry the formatting is messed up for some reason):

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspTheoLossGetRejectCodes]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT SelectCode, Description, MeltLineEnabled
    FROM   tblSelectCodes
    WHERE  (LanguageID = 1) AND (SelectCode >= 100) AND (MeltLineEnabled = 1) 
    ORDER BY Description

    SET NOCOUNT OFF;
END
```

Here is the VB6 function that assigns the RecordSet to the variable rsRetData:

```
Public Function TheoLossCalcRejectError()
Dim lErrorCode          As EBOD_ComponentErrorCodes
Dim sErrorDescription   As String
Dim objStoredProc       As StoredProcedure.IStoredProcedure


Set objStoredProc = CreateObject("StoredProcedure.IStoredProcedure")
With objStoredProc
    .NewStoredProcedure

    If .Open_Connection(lErrorCode, sErrorDescription) Then
    Set rsRetData = .ExecuteReturnRecordset(USPPARNAME_GETREJECTCODES, lErrorCode, sErrorDescription)
    End If
    .Close_Connection
End With
Set objStoredProc = Nothing

End Function
```

The function executes correctly and the RecordSet is assigned correctly.

How can I make this happen?

Comment: You would look at setting the datasource of your combobox to the recordset.

Comment: I tried that in the properties of the ComboBox but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you explain didn't work? Did you get an error message? You need to provide details so we can help.

Comment: Showing your code makes it possible for us to suggest things that might be causing issues and avoids us having to guess how you're doing things now.

Comment: Sean, I set rsRetData as the DataSource in the properties for cboxRejectReasons.  The form runs with no errors but the dropdown is empty.

Comment: If you've connected the datasource and the combobox remains empty, then there are no rows in the dataset. (Your stored procedure is incomplete, as it accepts no parameters as you've posted it here, but you're passing in parameters that apparently aren't being used.) And instead of apologizing because the formatting is bad, fix it. :-) Select all of the code and hit Ctrl+K on your keyboard or click the toolbar button with the image that looks like {}, or indent each line by at least 4 spaces. You can preview it in real-time as you format it by looking just below where you're typing the text.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding both text and an ID value to a VB6 combobox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11745622/adding-both-text-and-an-id-value-to-a-vb6-combobox)