# VB6 & .accdb database Login Form

Tags: ms-access, vb6

I am wondering if anyone can help me out with this issue. I have a login form with a combobox named cboUsername, and a textbox for the password named txtPassword. I have the form accessing the Employee table of the database, and fills the combobox with the Employee names from the field strEmpName in the .accdb, and I am having an issue checking the password against the same table with the field name strEmpPassword. What I'm trying to do is if the passwords match, then allow access to the software. Along with that, I have a field named strAccess that allows the user access to certain portions of the software. strAccess will either be "Admin", "User", or "Read Only". Can anyone aid me with a solution? The working code I have is as follows:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Form_Load()
Dim db_file As String
Dim statement As String
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

cboUsername.Text = "Select Username"

' Get the data.
db_file = App.Path
If Right$(db_file, 1) <> "\" Then db_file = db_file & "\"
db_file = db_file & "FluidFlo.accdb"

' Open a connection.
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.ConnectionString = _
    "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & "Data Source=" & db_file & ";" & "Persist Security Info=False"
conn.Open

' Select the data.
statement = "SELECT strEmpName FROM tblEmployees ORDER BY strEmpName"

' Get the records.
Set rs = conn.Execute(statement, , adCmdText)

' Load the results into the ComboBox
Do Until rs.EOF
    cboUsername.AddItem rs!strEmpName
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
' Close the recordset and connection.
rs.Close
conn.Close

End Sub
```

I hope I have made clear of what I am trying to accomplish, and as always, thanks to everyone in advance!

Comment: I am guessing that when checking the password against the database, I would write the code in the cmdLogin sub...my brain is hurting lol

Comment: If this is Access code then the [visual-studio] and [vb6] tags do not apply. But I am not sure where this codes resides. Is it in the accdb?

Comment: I'm writing in VB6 but accessing the database from within. Just using the database to store all the data. I have some code written, but it's not working properly. I will post it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a function yielding the Windows user name

```
Private Declare Function GetUserName Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias "GetUserNameA" (ByVal lpBuffer As String, nSize As Long) As Long

Public Function LoginName() As Variant
    Dim ret As Long
    Dim s As String * 255
    Dim pos As Long

    ret = GetUserName(s, 255)
    pos = InStr(s, vbNullChar)
    If pos <= 1 Then
        LoginName = Null
    Else
        LoginName = Left$(s, pos - 1)
    End If
End Function
```

Using this function you could just ask for the password with no need fill a ComboBox with user names.

Using this other function

```
Public Function SqlStr(ByVal s As String) As String
'Input: s=""      Returns: NULL
'Input: s="abc"   Returns: 'abc'
'Input: s="x'y"   Returns: 'x''y'

    If s = "" Then
        SqlStr = "NULL"
    Else
        SqlStr = "'" & Replace(s, "'", "''") & "'"
    End If
End Function
```

you can check the password with

```
If DCount("*", "tblEmployees", _
    "strEmpName = " & SqlStr(LoginName()) & " AND strPwd = " & SqlStr(txtPassword)) = 1 Then
    ...
Else
    ...
End If
```

Btw., if this code is in the accdb with the tables or in an accdb where these tables are linked to, then there is no need to create connections and to use ADODB. Just put this query `SELECT strEmpName FROM tblEmployees ORDER BY strEmpName` in the `Row Source` property of the ComboBox.

Note: This is Access VBA code.

---

**Update**

From you newly posted code I see that you are comparing an employee Id with an employee name (`[lngEmpID]=" & Me.cboUsername.Value`), which of course does not work.

Make sure the `Row Source Type` of the ComboBox is `Table/Query`. Put this code in the ComboBox's `Row Source` property.

```
SELECT lngEmpID, strEmpName FROM tblEmployees ORDER BY strEmpName
```

Compared to your code, this adds the Id. Set `Column Count` to `2` and `Column Widths` to `0cm`. This hides the Id column in the ComboBox. Now, the ComboBox's Value is the Id instead of the name.

Comment: See: [Adding both text and an ID value to a VB6 combobox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11745622/adding-both-text-and-an-id-value-to-a-vb6-combobox)

Comment: I have resolved the issue. Was quite easy. Thanks for everyone's advice